# c# copy file from textbox to selected directory

Tags: c#, wpf, filecopy

I'm working with c# on wpf and running into a problem where I select some files and their filenames go into my my 'filespicked' textbox. I then have a button that is supposed to copy the files, the same ones that were selected in the textbox, to another folder. This button opens up a folder browser dialog and I select the folder I want to copy to.

The problem is that when I select the folder and click ok, I get an exception caught by my try/catch exception handler and it does not copy.

Here is my code.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        dialog.Description = "Select a folder to copy to";
        dialog.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string[] files = filePickedTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Detect and handle the event of a non-valid filename
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(file, dialog.SelectedPath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    outputTextBox.Text = ex.ToString();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is the error:

System.IO.IOException: The target file "C:\Users\tj\Desktop\copied_files" is a directory, not a file.
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
at WpfApp1.MainWindow.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

The error makes no sense to me because the string in the file variable is the target file, not the copied_files folder. That is the destination folder.

Comment: How are you getting the file names? You can use [FileInfo.FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname?view=net-5.0) to get the full path of the file. You can also use [File.Exists(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) to validate the file path you're getting is valid.

Comment: I have another button which opens a filedialog and selects multiple files into the filespicked textbox. From here I am using them for other functions, without any problems. But when I try to copy, its giving me this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copy destination needs to be a file, not a directory (Hence "The target **file**..."). Use Path.Combine to tack the file name onto dialog.SelectedPath if you want to keep the same file name:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // Detect and handle the event of a non-valid filename
    try
    {
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(dialog.SelectedPath, Path.GetFileName(file)));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        outputTextBox.Text = ex.ToString();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! this change solved it. It is copying normally now